# How do i change a form's action on rendering a view? (aka via ViewBag or ViewData)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanted to what action a view called programmatically by specifying the action name via the ViewBag or ViewData components, but I was unable to do so. why!?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(ViewData["SubmitType"], "Person"))
{...
```

when I run this I get:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1928:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a
>   definition for 'BeginForm' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   string, string)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 11:  Line 12:  Line 13: @using
>   (Html.BeginForm(ViewData["SubmitType"], "Person")) Line 14: { Line 15:
>   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops! can't believe I forgot that the Viewdata and ViewBag are not going to hold the type string. I had to cast the return value, and everything worked!

```
@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewData["SubmitType"], "Person"))
{
```